# OS X Shell Script executable not working

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, symlink

I have a shell script that I'm trying to make executable.

Here's the script: (it doesn't do anything useful yet. just trying to get it to run properly)

```
#!/bin/sh

function rip_it_good(){
    echo "function called"
}

rip_it_good
```

First I made it executable:

```
$ chmod +x ripitgood.sh
```

So far, so good. If I run it from terminal in the local directory

```
$ ./ripitgood.sh
```

it runs just fine and I get the proper output of "function called".

Next I linked to it from /usr/local/bin

```
$ sudo ln -s ripitgood.sh /usr/local/bin/ripitgood
```

But if I try to run it using the newly created link:

```
$ ripitgood
```

I get an error

"-bash: ripitgood: command not found"

I checked, and *yes* /usr/local/bin is in my PATH

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin
```

*And* I tried to run it directly

```
$ /usr/local/bin/ripitgood
-bash: /usr/local/bin/ripitgood: No such file or directory
```

So, I opened up finder and checked, and yes, the link "ripitgood" exist in the /usr/local/bin directory

I can still run it from the directory where it resides:

```
./ripitgood.sh
function called
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in how you create the symlink:

```
sudo ln -s ripitgood.sh /usr/local/bin/ripitgood
```

The symlink will literally be `ripitgood.sh`, but there is no `ripitgood.sh` in `/usr/local/bin`. Try creating the symlink like this:

```
sudo ln -s $(pwd)/ripitgood.sh /usr/local/bin/ripitgood
```

That will use the full, absolute path to `ripitgood.sh` in the symlink.

Comment: Excellent. I had assumed it would take into account the fact that the script was in the PWD at the time that I ran the `ln -s` command.